# In Ubuntu 18.04 Unity, dragging windows turns them a solid gray color

Tags: unity, compiz, 18.04

In 18.04, I installed `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package, and restarted and logged in with Unity, and  whenever I drag a window it goes an ugly gray color (and doesn't wobbble, with wobbly windows turned on). Strangely, maximizing and minimizing does make them wobbly.

I'm on the latest (PPA) nVidia drivers and Compiz Config Manager has animations and everything turned on. It worked fine in Ubuntu 16 with the same setup.

Notably Unity transparency/blur also doesn't work.

Here is what happens when I drag:

[image: Gray windows]

Comment: with latest you mean... the .run package from the website or the official supported ubuntu repositories one?

Comment: The nVidia PPA latest, because the latest official one doesn't work well with my 144hz gaming monitor

Comment: this thing  is beyond my comprehension, all I know is that the website ones... are glitchy af... I recommend you to use the official suported.. and search in arch wiki for some scripts...

Comment: Maybe in CompizConfig Window Management > Move Window > Appearance, "Transparency" is unchecked?